# Fast way to check if target field of InputMethodEditor is empty

Tags: android, performance, android-softkeyboard

I am creating an Android IME (custom soft keyboard). I'd like to check if the target field is empty before I start to automatically fill it with custom text. In order to perform the check, I might call `getTextAfterCursor` and `getTextBeforeCursor`. This should work, but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#getTextAfterCursor%28int,%20int%29) says

> IME authors: please consider this will trigger an IPC round-trip that will take some time. Assume this method consumes a lot of time.

Calling such a method twice doesn't sound like a great idea. Is there any simple way to check if the text of the input field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to use getTextAfterCursor and getTextBeforeCursor. This needs to be explained.

Have you just tried:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(field.getText())
```

If you can't use this method, then you need to explain more.

**EDIT:** Do you have access to InputConnection in your code and it's method? Then you can try to do something useful in getExtractedText() method. Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325061/955107) you can find additional information for your solution.

Comment: what is `field`? Note: I am creating an Input Method, the field doesn't live in my process (and I don't have its context) so I cannot access it (as far as I know).

Comment: It is really difficult to answer your question, because actually no code is provided by you.

Comment: Sorry, I've finally got the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly then in onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) method you will fill field if it's empty.

Sorry, at the moment I don't know better solution then you have. Btw, how you will fill field?